# Convert XML file to datatable C#

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

I've the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<font id="plejd">
<glyph unicode="&#x100;" glyph-name="area_add" d="string" />
<glyph unicode="&#x101;" glyph-name="area_bathroom" d="string2" />
<glyph unicode="&#x102;" glyph-name="area_cabin" d="string3" />
<glyph unicode="&#x103;" glyph-name="area_cinema" d="string4" />
</font>
```

I would like to iterate through every item and add the unicode, glyph-name & d to a datatable.

I have the following code but I don't know how to get the info.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("PivotIcons.xml");
        foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants())
        {

        }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can do directly using LINQ

Comment: LINQ to XML will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
 public static void XMLToDataTable()
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\\Sample.xml");

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("unicode");
        dt.Columns.Add("glyph_name");
        dt.Columns.Add("d");
        string[] arr = new string[3];

        var dr = from n in doc.Descendants("glyph")
                 select new string[]{ 
                     arr[0] = n.Attribute("unicode").Value,
                     arr[1] = n.Attribute("glyph-name").Value,
                     arr[2] = n.Attribute("d").Value
                 };

        foreach (var item in dr)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item[0],item[1],item[2]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
        XElement root = XElement.Load("PivotIcons.xml");
        foreach (XElement element in root.Descendants("glyph"))
        {
            string unicode = element.Attribute("unicode").Value;
            string glyphname = element.Attribute("glyph-name").Value;
            string d = element.Attribute("d").Value;

            // save to database...?
        }
```

would do the job.  You'll need to format the unicode to how you plan on storing it in the database!