# How to get the value from a XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to extract the values from the following xml sample:

```
<myPrices>
  <Prices Date="10-Oct-18" ReportName="myReport">
    <Record RecordId="1">
      <COLUMN DisplayName="Start Date" FormalName="startdate">11.10.2018</COLUMN>
      <COLUMN DisplayName="End Date" FormalName="Price">10</COLUMN>
    </Record>
    <Record RecordId="2">
      <COLUMN DisplayName="Start Date" FormalName="startdate">11.10.2018</COLUMN>
      <COLUMN DisplayName="End Date" FormalName="Price">20</COLUMN>
    </Record>
  </Prices>
</myPrices>
```

So for the above I want the values 10 and 20.

I have the following so far (from [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346867/convert-xml-file-to-datatable-c-sharp)) but this gives me the value for `FormalName` i.e. `startdate` and `price`.

```
string[] arr = new string[3];
var dr = from n in prices.Descendants("COLUMN")
         select new string[]
         {
             arr[0] = n.Attribute("FormalName").Value
         };

foreach (var item in dr)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(item[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the value of `FormalName` because that is what you are selecting. What you want is to filter out only `COLUMN`s where their attribute of `FormalName` equals `"Price"` and then retrieve the value of the element:

```
var result = prices.Descendants("COLUMN")
                   .Where(e => e.Attribute("FormalName")?.Value == "Price")
                   .Select(e => e.Value);
```

Which IMO will look now a bit cleaner in query syntax:

```
var result = from c in prices.Descendants("COLUMN")
             where c.Attribute("FormalName")?.Value == "Price"
             select c.Value;
```